# Backendless - Composition of table id

Tags: field, backendless

I have created a `table` in Backendless and I would like to know if I can compose the `table id` with 2 fields like in a `SQL table`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backendless automatically assigns a unique identifier to every inserted object. There is a system column named "objectId". Additionally, you can assign constraints to your table which can be:

- Indexed
- Not null
- Unique

.